# Trait Subtractable issue after upgrading from Scala 2.11.11 to Scala 2.12.3

Tags: scala, playframework

I migrated my Scala Play! application from Scala 2.11.11 to Scala 2.12.3

Since then, I obtain the following error when compiling my app:

```
type arguments [?,Equals] do not conform to trait Subtractable's type parameter bounds [A,+Repr <: scala.collection.generic.Subtractable[A,Repr]]
[error]       for (req <- request.req.getRequestList) {
[error]                               ^
[error] one error found
```

For some reason, Scala 2.12 seems to have problem iterating over Java Array.

The getRequestList returns the following object: Array[Req].

Did anyone encountered this issue?

Here is the part of the code where I am encountering the issue:

```
  // Sorting the requests by Certificate Authority
  for (req <- request.req.getRequestList) {
    // Extracting the Key Hash from the request
    val keyHash = getKeyHash(req)
    // Extracting the Name Hash from the request
    val nameHash = getNameHash(req)
    // Retrieving the CA from the Key Hash or Name Hash
    val ca = keyHash.flatMap(getCertificateAuthorityFromKeyHash).map { ca =>
      Logger.debug(s"[${self.path.name}] - CA found based on Issuer Key Hash ('${keyHash.getOrElse("NA").toUpperCase}') -> '${ca.name}'")
      ca
    } orElse nameHash.flatMap(getCertificateAuthorityFromNameHash).map { ca =>
      Logger.debug(s"[${self.path.name}] - CA found based on Issuer Name Hash ('${nameHash.getOrElse("NA").toUpperCase}') -> '${ca.name}'")
      ca
    } getOrElse {
      Logger.debug(s"[${self.path.name}] - Unable to find CA based on Issuer Key Hash ('${keyHash.getOrElse("NA").toUpperCase}') and Name Hash ('${nameHash.getOrElse("NA").toUpperCase}'. Discarding request with Unauthorized status)")
      throw new UnknownCertificateAuthorityException("CertificateID does not reference a registered Certificate Authority")
    }
    if (reqsByCA.contains(ca.id.get)) {
      reqsByCA(ca.id.get) += req
    } else {
      reqsByCA += (ca.id.get -> ArrayBuffer(req))
    }
  }
```

The request.re.getRequestList returns an Array of org.bouncycastle.cert.ocsp.Req (Array[org.bouncycastle.cert.ocsp.Req]).

Comment: Show us your code.

Answer (score 0):

After further investigation, the problem was coming from this line:

```
reqsByCA(ca.id.get) += req
```

I replaced it by:

```
reqsByCA(ca.id.get).append(req)
```

Which to me is strictly equivalent...

And now it compiles and run.

If someone could explain my why, I would greatly appreciate.

Anyway, my problem is solved.